# Как изменить HTML код сайта в интернете через Java Script?

Tags: javascript, html

господа! Я новичок в теме сайтов, но имею опыт программирования на других языках. Я делаю расширение для Google Chrome, у меня есть URL страницы и мне нужно поменять некоторые параметры в HTML коде этой страницы, для того что бы показать пользователю нужный контент.

Например:

Было:
`<div id="trade_escrow_header" class="trade_escrow_header responsive_trade_offersection" style="display: none">`

Должно стать:
`<div id="trade_escrow_header" class="trade_escrow_header responsive_trade_offersection" style="display: block">`

То есть, нужно поменять параметр style из "display: none" на "display: block".
Можно ли это сделать с помощью какой то функции в Java Script? Если нет, то каким простим способом это можно сделать?

Comment: javaScript  как и другие языки чем-то лучше, чем-то хуже. Но это не магия, просто браузер предоставляет  javaScript  WEB API, таким образом у  js  появляется мост к вебу. Например получение елимента, его изменение, вывод, добавление и остальные операции, а так же слушатели событий, это все  web-api. Для изменения стиля инлайном воспользуйтесь получением элемента, у него найдите  style  в котором есть объект display , а затем присвойте нужное вам значение. Или добавьте в  css  класс и используйте classList.метод()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`document.getElementById('trade_escrow_header').style.display = 'block';`